# Combinar diccionarios

Tags: python, diccionarios

Necesito de su ayuda.
Tengo 2 diccionarios que son los siguientes:

```
newDataPagare = {'folio': 'SGDATA123', 'monto': '65,800', 'deudor': 'Pedro Ramirez', 'curpDeudor': 'PERM940617MDFVRR04', 'acreedor': 'Juan Perez', 'curpAcreedor': 'PECJ860524MDFVRR01', 'suma': 'Sesenta y Cinco Mil Ochocientos', 'vencimiento': '2022-02-16', 'tasaMensual': '7%', 'jurisdiccion': 'Ciudad de mexico', 'fecha': '2022-02-16', 'url': 'http://expediente.com/id+11'}

newDataEndoso = {'nuevoAcreedor': 'Emiliano Espinoza', 'curpNuevoAcreedor': 'EMHJ970214MDFVRR03', 'lugarDeFirma': 'Ciudad de mexico', 'fechaEndoso': '2022-02-16'}
```

Del diccionario **newDataPagare** necesito agregar los valores específicos que son **folio, deudor, curpDeudor y url** al diccionario **newDataEndoso**.

No encuentro la manera de como hacerlo creen que me puedan apoyar por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sería algo tan sencillo como darle valor al diccionario `newDataEndoso` el valor de una key de `newDataPagare`:

```
newDataEndoso['key'] = newDataPagare['key']
```

Quedando así:

```
newDataEndoso['folio'] = newDataPagare['folio']
newDataEndoso['deudor'] = newDataPagare['deudor']
newDataEndoso['curpDeudor'] = newDataPagare['curpDeudor']
newDataEndoso['url'] = newDataPagare['url']
```

Lo que haces es crear una nueva key en el diccionario newDataEndoso con la key que quieres añadir, y luego le añades el valor de newDataPagare con esa key.